# Karma coverage does not fail the build when the coverage requirements are not met

Tags: angular, karma-runner, nrwl-nx, nrwl, karma-coverage

I'm using [NX from NRWL](https://nx.dev/) with my [Angular](https://angular.io/) app and I run the unit tests in my CI using the following command:

```
nx affected:test --base=main --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox --codeCoverage --parallel=true --maxParallel=4
```

when the code coverage requirements are not met the build still passes despite I can clearly see the coverage error in the build log:

> 07 12 2022 16:06:14.750:ERROR [coverage]: Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.91 (Linux x86_64): Coverage for branches (99.68%) does not meet global threshold (100%)

how can I tell nx to make this command fail as soon as the coverage requirements are not met?

EDIT: even running just one single project's test has the same problem:

```
nx run one-single-project:test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox --codeCoverage=true
```

If I now `echo $?` it will be `0` but it should be error instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was unrelated to `nx`.

I figured out after a couple of hours of debugging that it was about `karma-coverage` and its config.

In my `karma.config.js`:

```
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      subdir: '.',
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      reporters: [{ type: 'text-summary'}, { type: 'html' }, { type: 'lcovonly', subdir: './' }],
      check: {
        global: {
          statements: 100,
          lines: 100,
          branches: 100,
          functions: 100,
        },
      },
    },
```

More specifically, inside `reporters` I had `{ type: 'text-summary' }` which was missing the `file` property and for some reasons it failed the coverage check. So the correct way is: `{ type: 'text-summary', file: 'coverage.txt' }`

The full `coverageReporter` config now looks like this:

```
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      subdir: '.',
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      reporters: [{ type: 'text-summary', file: 'coverage.txt' }, { type: 'html' }, { type: 'lcovonly', subdir: './' }],
      check: {
        global: {
          statements: 100,
          lines: 100,
          branches: 100,
          functions: 100,
        },
      },
    },
```

I believe this is a bug of [karma-coverage](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/) and I have submitted [a fix](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/485) for it.

Comment: Fwiw, I deployed a scoped version of `karma-coverage` including Francesco's PR's changes (which have been sitting since December) to npmjs. Details here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/485#issuecomment-1587666646 Thanks for the detailed explanation, issue, and PR fix.